# AngularJS - Why using anonymous controller in directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, directive, anonymous

This is my source of information:

"The controllerAs option enables us to set a controller alias, thus allowing us to publish our controller under this name and giving the scope access to the controllerAs name. This step allows us to reference the controller from inside the view and even allows us to need to inject $scope.

This option may seem trivial, but in gives us a lot of power in how we can use and create anonymous controllers in our routers and directives. That power allows us to create dynamic objects as controllers that are isolated and easy to test.

For instance, we can create an anonymous controller in a directive like so:"

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp",[]);
myApp.directive('myDirective', function(){
  return{
    restrict: 'A',
    template: '<h4> {{myController.msg}} </h4>',
    controllerAs: 'myController',
    controller: function(){
      this.msg = "Hello world";
    }
  };
});
```

What is the functionality of anonymous controllers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Equivalent code without controllerAs would look something like:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp",[]);
myApp.directive('myDirective', function(){
  return{
    restrict: 'A',
    template: '<h4> {{myController.msg}} </h4>',
    controller: function($scope){
      $scope.myController = this;
      this.msg = "Hello world";
    };
});
```

You might use something like this in order to introduce better namespacing for nested directives. So if you have a parent and child controller, instead of putting a property like 'name' on the scope of each, you could assign the name to the actual controller (this.name = 'the name') and then access these names from the controllers assigned to the scope:

```
myApp.directive('myParentDirective', function(){
  return{
    restrict: 'A',
    template: '<div class="parent"><div my-child></div></div>',
    controllerAs: 'parent'
    controller: function($scope){
      this.name = "parent";
  };
}).directive('myChildDirective', function(){
  return{
    restrict: 'A',
    template: '<div class="child">parent name ="{{ parent.name }}"</div>' +
              '<div class="child">child name = "{{ child.name }}"</div>',
    controllerAs: 'child'
    controller: function($scope){
    this.name = "child";
  };
});
```

Comment: 1. Is not injecting a $scope not necessary to get the "anonymous controller" behaviour.
2. Why does it say that this way is easier to test?

Comment: 3. Is it necessary for the directives to be nested in order to take advantage of this functionality. Which could be another case?

4. When nested, does the scope: (true- false- {}) interact with this functionality, inheriting or not the controller's scope?

Comment: 1) You can still inject a scope into the controller; you wouldn't be able to access parent from the child controller in my example otherwise. 2) IMO it's more explicit where properties came from if they're prefixed with a controller name; otherwise they could have come from anywhere in the $scope inheritance.

Comment: 3) As I show in the first example, it's the equivalent to assigning the controller to a $scope. So anytime you could get access to the scope (such as using element.scope()), you could take advantage of controllerAs. 4) Normal scoping rules apply, so you would need to use an isolate scope for your directive if you wanted the option to define sibling elements of the directive without conflict.